# Библиотека не зарегистрирована. visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался, что делать?
О какой библиотеке идет речь?

---

В ***Visual Studio 2015***, при попытке создать новый проект, открывается окно ошибки:

> Библиотека не зарегистрирована.(Искулючение из HRESULT:   0x8002801D
>   (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))

[image: Example]

Comment: Вы не могли бы потрудиться и сформулировать ваш вопрос в читаемой форме. После удаления картинок с сервера здесь никто тогда не поймёт о чём идёт речь.

Comment: судя по всему, было установлено левое расширение для студии.

Comment: Когда возникает эта ошибка? Сразу при запуске студии? При запуске какого-то проекта? И да, во временно́м отрезке между «всё работало» и «сейчас не работает» никаких обновлений не загружали, программ не устанавливали?

Comment: Ошибка возникает, при запуске какого-либо проекта и при попытке создать новый проект.
2 недели назад визуалка работала, никаких обновлений, программ не устанавливала.

Comment: Вам правильно подсказывают, попробуйте по очереди отключать расширения и плагины и смотреть не пропадет ли ошибка.